# What generally happens if a department is unable to attract students?

Tags: university

Say the math department used to teach 200 students, but because each year the number of students interested in math has decreased, now it only teaches 100 students. What are the usual practical consequences?

This clearly depends on the internal policy of the institute, but I wonder if some generalizations are possible, e.g. whether the department will be forced to downsize or whether people outside the department will intervene and try to help the department get more students.

Comment: It sounds like this would very much depend on the university and who's in charge. Maybe the dean is a mathematics professor, or maybe he just hates math and is looking for an excuse to get rid of it.

Comment: You seem to believe that the number of students is a function of the quality of the program...? Anyway, an answer would at least depend on the country (for example, "Will some math faculty lose their jobs since the university has lower revenue" is an unequivocal "no" in e.g. France, but apparently not in the US), or even the institution in question. This question is way too broad.

Comment: Sure, this question is broad, but answerers can clarify to which country, field, etc. their answer applies. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I don't agree this question is off topic. The help center explicitly says questions about "Inner workings of research departments" is within scope. Voting to reopen.

Comment: reopen this question, it is important for academia, also not fair @Maarten Buis he gave good answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As comments already indicate, this is hugely dependent on the country and university.

When I was in the Netherlands funding of the university was directly related to the number of students and the number of students who finished. This dependency was passed on by the universities to the departments. Typically, there was some sort of delay build in, so the budget would not become too unpredictable.

Usually fluctuations are not as dramatic as in your scenario, and smaller decreases can usually be covered by reducing the budget for conference visits, inviting speakers, etc.

However if the number of students halfs then cuts in personel are pretty much unavoidable, as personel is by far the largest post in the budget. However, firing people on a permanent contract is hard. It is much much easier to not prolong a temporary contract. The department usualy consisted of a small number of professors (on permanent contract) plus a larger number of lecturers (some on a permanent contract and some on a temporary contract). So the professors and lecturers on a permament contract are safe, but they will have a smaller department.

So this is a case where there was an explicit policy to add such a feedback. However, this description is specific to the Netherlands (and may not even be current). Other countries are organized differently. Even within countries there can be a difference between universities or types of universities.

Comment: I guess if the change happens over a long enough time period the other solution is to simply not replace those who retire.

Comment: @IanSudbery That usually not a viable strategy. There are often only 4 or 5 persons on a permanent contract in a department. The chance that one of those retires at the right moment is very slim. Moreover, as I said in the answer, there are very few professors in a Dutch department and they fulfill crucial management roles. Not replacing those is often just not an option.

Comment: Differences between systems I suppose. My department has 35 permanent academic staff and our maths department has similar. Although there are only a small number of professors (i.e. chairs), when one retires, someone will move up to replace them, but if necessary no junior member will be hired to replace the promoted lecturer. Recently my dept. came out of a period when no one had been hired for 10 years.